# How to register the message notification in ios5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am developing an application in ios5 and i need the code to get notification when a message arrives as well as when a message dispatches. I have the code to fire the notification for every 10 seconds. But i want to receive a notification, when message arrives or dispatches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a look at this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html), and use the correct delegate method (assuming you are talking about push notifications).

E.g.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Remote (Push) and local notification delegates:

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
application:didReceiveLocalNotification:
```